# Why set a function parameters default value on javascript function work like this?

Tags: javascript

javascript code like this

```
function foo (x = 2,y = function(){return x;}){
   var x = 5;
   console.log(y())  // 2
}
foo();
```

console output  2,it's looks like the parameters has own scope and closure the parameter  x .until i see this result:

```
function foo (x = 2,y = function(){return x;}){
  x = 5;
  console.log(y()) // 5  WTF?
}
foo();
```

console output 5.this is really confused me.Is keyword var make a redeclaration and be ignore?but looks not work like this.
How this code really work in this case?

Comment: @sp00m No global variable, no. It's still a local variable declared by the named parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of `x` is localized when `var`/`let`/`const` is used.

When `y` is defined `y = function(){return x;}` in the argument list, scope of `x` and `y` is defined when the **expression is evaluated at the time of definition of function** `foo`.

While, when `var` is used, scope of `x` is localized again and older `y` still retain older bindings of `x`.

These values are not overwritten even if you pass parameters to `foo`

```
foo(1,function(){});
```

still outputs `5` if the `var` wasn't used (and the variable's scope wasn't localized hence new value is used), however with `var` the value is overwritten and it gives `1`.